# How to hide an AntD message after another Promise (API request) completes?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to make an API call. When the API call started I display a loading message. I want to stop showing this message when the API call is a success.

This is the message I am using now

```
message.loading({
    content: "Loading...",
    duration: 0,});
```

I don't know how to stop the message when the API call is a success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `message.loading` (and other functions, like `message.success`, `message.info`, etc) return a function that closes the message-box when invoked. This is demonstrated in this sample [from their doc](https://ant.design/components/message/)s:

```
const showThenHide = () => {
  // This starts showing the message:
  const hide = message.loading('Action in progress..', 0);

  setTimeout(hide, 2500); // <-- This invokes the `hide` function after 2.5 seconds
};

showThenHide();
```

---

I assume you already have a `Promise<T>` that represents your API request in-progress. In which case:

```
const hideMessage = message.loading('Loading..', /*duration:*/ 0);

try {
    
    const apiRequestPromise = someApiClient.doSomething();
    const apiRequestRespons = await apiRequestPromise; // You can also inline this await

    renderApiResponse( apiRequestRespons );
}
catch ( err ) {
    // TODO: Error-handling
}
finally {
    hideMessage();
}
```

It's important to have the `hideMessage()` invocation in a `finally` block and *not* just after the `await apiRequestPromise` because if an exception is thrown inside the `try` block (or if you don't have a `try` block at all) then the message will remain open indefinitely, which isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0):

if you had checked the document of antd about [message](https://ant.design/components/message/#header) you would see how they destroy the loading message there:

- message.loading(..) return `hide` function when excute.
- to hide the loading, simply call the `hide` message.

so I can give you an example to handle asynchronous API call:

```js
const hide = message.loading('Loading...',0)
API.getUser(id).then(res => {
  //handle response
  hide()
}
```

Comment: In the OP's defense, Antd's documentation doesn't make this obvious as all-but-1 of their examples shows it auto-hiding instead of being manually dismissed. It's also made even more difficult to grok because the `hide` function _is also_ a `Promise`. That's poor API design, imo.

Comment: yeah you have to read the sample code. And yes, I agree with you that a PR for document's improvement is sweet